# A shader that changes all surfaces to black or white depending on amount of light hitting the object

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine, shader-nodes

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I want an **eevee** shader that detects if an object is in direct light, say from a sunlight source. It then paints the ENTIRE object white, not just a surface. If the object is in shade, it paints the ENTIRE object black. Is there any way to achieve this?